# How to get method name in spring filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I want retrieve the method name or class name from request in filter method.

Please let me know any possible ways.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I am able to achieve using below snippet. Thanks for you time.

```
 RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappings1 = (RequestMappingHandlerMapping) ApplicationContextHolder.getBean("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = mappings1.getHandlerMethods();
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = mappings1.getHandler(httpServletRequest);
        if(Objects.nonNull(handler)){
            HandlerMethod handler1 = (HandlerMethod) handler.getHandler();}
```

Comment: ApplicationContextHolder is from which class? I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: please reply ApplicationContextHolder  question

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from the question, you are looking to retrieve some information from Web filters (like OncePerRequestFilter of Spring or so)

> retrieve the method name or class name from request in filter method

At this point, there is no class or method, it's just an httpInputStream. All you can do is, just byte operations, or read it as string and do String operations, or deserialize it to more Structured (For Example using Jackson deserialize json string to Java Objects/ Using JAXB deserializing XML to Java Objects)

Comment: I want method name of that Request URL. Its a spring rest API. I want to retrieve the method that it mapped.

Comment: you want the spring mvc controller's method (which served/will-serve this request) in a web filter? At web filter, you won't have any clue about that, If your web filter comes after the Spring MVC filters you have couple of options.. either you can derive the method name based on the response structure or you can add a header to the response at your controller so that you can identify the method which served the request

Comment: let me know the use case of this requirement, probably I can help